# Is it possible to indicate direction on a line in CartoDB?

Tags: carto

I am working on a project that involves mapping journeys, and I am wondering whether there is a way to indicate the direction of the journey on a line in CartoDB. For example, could the direction of the line be indicated with an arrow on the line, or with a color change along the line?

Comment: CartoDB uses [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) in which you can use this article on [how to add an arrow to a line in leaflet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654143/good-way-to-draw-a-directional-arrowed-marker-in-leaflet). or take a look at this GitHub on [Leaflet Arrows](https://github.com/meteotest/leaflet-arrows) - [Here](http://meteotest.github.io/leaflet-arrows/) is a real example of the GitHub implemented

Comment: Or you can take a look at this [GitHub](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.TextPath) with Leaflet is working great!

I added a new polyline with the coordinates of the preexisting lines on my map, and I set the opacity of the line to 0 so that the arrows would show up but the line would not. An offset of 4 made the arrows line up properly with the preexisting lines.

```
var testing = L.polyline([[41.6484, 13.6099], [41.4922, 13.7056], ... [37.3973, 25.2682]], {
                weight: 0,
                color: '#ffffff',
                opacity: 0
            }).addTo(map);
    testing.setText('>             ', {repeat: true,
                        offset: 4,
                        attributes: {fill: '#ffffff',
                                     'font-weight': 'bold',
                                      'font-size': '10'}});
```

The only limitation is that I have some buttons on my map that filter the points and lines with SQL, and the arrows are not affected by the filtering. Still looking for a solution to this issue.

Comment: Could you please provide some detail on how this answers your original question?

Comment: I've added more details. It doesn't look like CartoDB understands directionality, but Leaflet does.